# How to execute maven tasks in eclipse (Sonatype plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I know it must be something simple, but I just can't figure it out..

I'm using the Sonatype maven plugin on eclipse. When I want to build a war file for a webapp project, the only way I know to do it is to use the command line and type mvn package.

I've looked all through the right click menu and I can't find any way to do it from eclipse.

There's a maven submenu that seems to have no options to do with building, and there's a run menu that doesn't seem right - I don't want to run my project - I just want to build it. There is a maven build option in the run menu, but if I run it, a configuration window pops up for me to enter goals in..

How I do I just do a simple mvn package, but through gui? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Thanks guys!
Both responses answer my question..
Now I have new problems that the build doesn't work, but I'll post that in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into the menu under that "Run As" there you find "Maven build" with a dialog where you can define different goals etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is a Maven project, **right-click** on your project and select **Run As** > **Maven Build** to create your own configuration (goals, profiles, etc) or use one of the preexisting configuration.

http://www.imagebanana.com/img/ja7wh7m0/screenshot_008.png

Once you've run a **Maven Build** Run Configuration, it will also be listed under the "**Run As...**" green arrow:

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8510/screenshotrun.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8510/screenshotrun.png)

You could add it as favorite if you want.